# Remove / stop JavaScript function that are already loaded, from running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to manipulate a site. When the site loads it initialize a script, Codaslider http://www.ndoherty.biz/2009/10/coda-slider-2/

How can I stop it from running? Is it possible to remove it before document ready?

The function I want to remove is:

```
$(function () {
      $("#coda-slider-1").codaSlider({slideEffect: "easeInOutExpo"
                                      , autoSlideInterval: 5500});
});
```

I've tried

```
$('#coda-slider-1').codaslider().stop();
```

and

```
$.codaSlider().stop();
```

without any luck. Is the last example possible?

Is it possible to remove the codaslider script entirely? Since I'm trying to manipulate a site that already have loaded the script. How can I dynamically erase / stop the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the script but if that is loaded first it will still run. You are in kind of a sucky situation there... To remove the script remove it like you remove any element. But if part of script was loaded and started running there is not much you can do. You can also remove some required field for the script so it will crash and make an error handler but for this you would need access to the script witch you don't.

If you manage to find a nice and clear way to remove it please post it. I'm quite interested since all I found were workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but it reset the script.

```
$.fn.codaSlider = function(settings) {
   //empty
};
```